# Restrict Jquery Animation for certain event only

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have sliding menu where I am using mouseover and mouseout method to trigger an animation. It is working but when frequently hovering and mouseout, animation continues for a long duration. How can I restrict it to only animate on over and out. Here is the sample code I used.

```
var slide_speed = 400;
$( ".fos-zoom-div" ).mouseover(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        marginTop: "-40px",
        cursor: "pointer"
     }, slide_speed, function() {

     });
});

$( ".fos-zoom-div" ).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).animate({
        marginTop: "0",
        cursor: "pointer"
        }, slide_speed, function() {

        });
});
```

Comment: You need to wrap those functions into a logic that blocks additional animation starts whilst an animation is currently active. You can do that by either using a flag indicating ongoing activity or by using the event raised by jquery when an animation has finished.

Comment: stop running animation on mouseover: https://api.jquery.com/stop/  `$(this).stop(true).animate({...});`

Comment: Use [`.mouseenter()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`.mouseleave()`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead.

Comment: thanks arkascha, it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the start, when the animation is just about to trigger, you can check whether the element is *currently being animated*, using [jQuery `is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```
$( ".fos-zoom-div" ).mouseover(function() {
   if($(this).is(':animated')){
      return false;
   }
   $(this).animate({
     marginTop: "-40px",
     cursor: "pointer"
     /** ... */
```

If the element ***is*** in animated state, returning false will disallow the *new* animation to get into the queue.